# ffmpeg - overlay with fade-out only

Tags: video, ffmpeg, watermark

I'm trying to overlay a video with multiple images and have each fade in/out at a specific point in the video.

What I'm attempting:

```
ffmpeg -i doodle.mp4 -loop 1 -i ban.png -loop 1 -i intro.png -loop 1 -i outro.png -c:a copy -filter_complex "[1:v]fade=in:st=0:d=0,fade=out:st=58:d=0[watermark0]; [2:v]fade=in:st=0:d=0,fade=out:st=10:d=0.5[watermark1]; [0:v][watermark0]overlay=(main_w-overlay_w)/2:main_h-overlay_h:shortest=1[tmp0]; [tmp0][watermark1]overlay=(main_w-overlay_w)/2:main_h-overlay_h" doodle2.mp4
```

The images can be seen fading in despite duration and starttime being set to 0. How can this be avoided?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want fade-ins, you don't need those filters.

```
ffmpeg -i doodle.mp4 -loop 1 -i ban.png -loop 1 -i intro.png -loop 1 -i outro.png -c:a copy
       -filter_complex "[1:v]fade=out:st=58:d=0[watermark0]; 
                        [2:v]fade=out:st=10:d=0.5[watermark1]; 
           [0:v][watermark0]overlay=(main_w-overlay_w)/2:main_h-overlay_h:shortest=1[tmp0];
           [tmp0][watermark1]overlay=(main_w-overlay_w)/2:main_h-overlay_h" doodle2.mp4
```

Now, ban.jpg and intro.png will only fade out. Note that outro.png isn't being used anywhere.